# How to check if the name doesn't contain two dots going together with regex?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string, and I want to check if this name doesn't contain exactly 2 dots combined:

```
"p.a.s@siv" - false 
"p..as@siv" - true 
"p...as@siv" - false
```

Is it possible to check this using regular expressions and python?

I found here and tried this pattern:

```
$pattern = '/^([^\.]|([^\.])\.[^\.])*$/';
```

but it doesn't work properly in first and third case. As I understood, it means that we check a symbol and it's not dot OR we check the symbol and this is not dot and the next following symbol is a dot and the next after next is not a dot.

Comment: what would be your expected output if the i/p is `p...as..f` ?

Comment: Why not simply `'..' in 'a..b'`?

Comment: `'..' in 'a...b'` also returns `True` @MaxNoe -  which is not what @paus needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a negative lookaround based regex.

```
if re.search(r'(?<!\.)\.\.(?!\.)', s):
    print 'Contain two dots'
```

`(?<!\.)` asserts that the match won't be preceded by a dot.`(?!\.)` asserts that the match won't be followed by a dot.